# Docker service worker not starting in stack deploy from the swarm votingapp tutorial

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have followed the swarm voting [lab](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/votingapp.md) from docker and after deploying `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-stack.yml vote` every service except one starts, while one gets stuck with status `preparing`. `docker service logs vote_worker` is empty and I have tried deploying twice and creating the service manually and it always freezes before the container gets created. I can't figure out why.

```
docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                          PORTS
mnidupsayek0        vote_db             replicated          1/1                 postgres:9.4
vbuskn6gvfrd        vote_redis          replicated          1/1                 redis:alpine                                   *:30001->6379/tcp
xsr0i67zortf        vote_result         replicated          1/1                 dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:after    *:5001->80/tcp
mpr7pbeub2yj        vote_visualizer     replicated          1/1                 dockersamples/visualizer:stable                *:8080->8080/tcp
9gqc6jgelil7        vote_vote           replicated          2/2                 dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:after      *:5000->80/tcp
ga0eoqcaioe0        vote_worker         replicated          0/1                 dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest
```

Comment: In general `preparing` means image download.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu agreed. I created the container created by the service manually as well and none of the layers were already downloaded. I've had problems with the pulls from the start. But after redeploying after manually creating the container, (which downloaded the image) the service still hangs. I figured it would be accessible once downloaded seperately